# keep session connected in a local shiny app

Tags: r, http, shiny

I made a simple desktop application using shiny package mainly for its UI, but there is a problem:

> After using `shiny::runApp()` to start my simple application in Windows desktop (localhost) with a long term task at the back-end, I noticed that the task will be shutdown after 6-7 hours regardless whether it has been completed. There is no any error (or warning) message, although I keep web browser (Chrome) open all the time.
>
> I suspect that this is because there is some kind of max connection time for each session, but I can't find it in the reference manual.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows how can I keep my back-end long term task running forever? Or how can I change setting for the max connection time for the session?

Note: this is not in the Shiny server, but a simple R shiny package.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research, I found a way, although it might be not the correct way or use-case for this.

All in all, it solved my problem!

the solution is:
`session$allowReconnect( "force" )`